# Изменение иконки приложения в status bar при api 26+

Tags: android, icon

Как поменять иконку приложения рядом с часами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для создания уведомлений использую NotificationCompat.Builder

```
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
```

но оба метода не работают. Хотя на старых версиях иконки отображаются. В mipmap у меня лежит абсолютно не такая иконка

Comment: Это иконка при получении уведомления ?

Comment: Да, верно. Хочу поменять саму иконку, а не только цвет: смена цвета работает только при вытянутой шторке builder.setColor(c.getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor));

Comment: Попробуйте в манифест добавить это: `<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/star"/>`

Comment: А куда конкретно это нужно добавить? В manifest, да? Не в тег application внутри manifest?

Comment: В application, можете добавить в конец, вот так: `<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/star"/>
    </application>`

Comment: Нужна иконка с прозрачным фоном

Comment: Да, нужна была просто прозрачная иконка, теперь все работает.